Is black doomed?
I recently found myself in this position. I was playing black and I lost the game.
[Title ""]
[Fen "2R5/P3k2p/8/3b2p1/2Pb1p2/5P2/6PP/5K2 b - - 0 1"]

My opponent was willing to try from this scenario several times.  As far as we could determine, black cannot win. (Assuming white doesn't blunder.)  Are we correct?  Or is there some brilliant move from black that can let them win?
It seems like black is going to lose a bishop regardless, but is there something I'm not seeing?

You're not missing anything; Black is toast. A bishop is threatened and 1...Bb7 is met by 2. Rc7+ and Rxb7 followed by a8=Q. 1...Bxa7 avoids the immediate promotion, but after 2. cxd5 White is up an exchange and a pawn with ready-made targets to attack. Game over. Black can resign.

Engine: +6.0. Toasted enough.
